# AWS Api Gateway: NodeJs post request - "Authorization not configured" on cognito logged in user

Tags: node.js, https, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have been trying to access my lambda using a POST, with Nodejs on login.

I am getting the error:

> Authorization not configured

I am using the ID token captured at login success. I have my cognito account as an authorization resource in my Gateway configuration. My token source is "Authorization".

My code is:

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
        var authToken = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
        console.log("Logged in");
        requestSignature(authToken);
    },  

    onFailure: function(err) {
        console.log(err)
        authToken = ''
    },  

});

function requestSignature(authToken) {

    var request = require('request');

    headers = { 
            Authorization: authToken,
    }   
    data = { 
        key : "key",
        bucket : "test"
    }   

    var options = { 
        method: 'POST',
        uri: invoke_url+'/getsignature',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: headers
        data: data
    };

    request.post(options,(err, response, body) => {
        if (response.statusCode < 300) {
            return callback(null, {
                statusCode: '200',
                body: res,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            });
        } else {
            console.log(response)
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was specifically in the API Gateway Test utility.

In my lambda function

```
if (!event.requestContext.authorizer) {
      errorResponse('Authorization not configured', context.awsRequestId, callback);
      return;
    }
```

Was getting tripped up because the Authorization header can't be passed into the Method Test utility and also grab a cognito ID for some reason.

When I removed that line I recieved a SUCCESS response. When I return the event that was passed into the lambda I received no "authorizer" in the requestContext.

This lead me to believe the Authorization was not functioning correctly. I removed the Authorization header and token compeletely and I received the same successful lambda response with the same requestContext.

When I returned to my application, I received this error when I do not have my authorizationId Token:

```
'{"message":"Unauthorized"}'
```

When I add the Authorization I receive a successful Lambda request with this in the request context:

```
"authorizer":
  {"claims":
    {"sub":"ba<>",
     "aud":"4v<>",
     "email_verified":"true",
     "event_id":"<>",
     "token_use":"id",
     "auth_time":"1530899925",
     "iss":"https://cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<cognito-id>",
     "cognito:username":"tester",
     "exp":"<>",
     "iat":"<>", 
     "email":"<>@<>"}},
     "resourcePath":"/<>",
     "httpMethod":"POST",
     "extendedRequestId":"<>",
     "requestTime":"<>",
     "path":"<>",
     "accountId":"<>",
```

Authorization is required in my app and the appropriate context is returned.

The issues of Cognito Authorization are then solely within the API Gateway Test.